# How to let user create fields and save records as choice lists? - Django rest framework

Tags: database, dataframe, data-structures, model, django-rest-framework

I would like to create a Management System, when I create a `Project`, project contains many `TaskGroup` such as "To do", "Doing" and "Done", and which is the default type of `TaskGroup` called `DefaultTaskGroup`, and Admin can create some other `TaskGroup` with different fields CharField, TextField, DateTimeField, Single or Multiple Choice.,etc, which will be save as `TaskGoup1 with new field 1 and new field 2`, `TaskGroup2 with new field 3 and new field 4`, if I created a new task, I can choose the type of `TaskGroup` from taskgroup lists(Default Task Group, TaskGroup1 and TaskGroup2).

I created partial models as below, they are not right, but I am puzzled about the database structure. Thank for reading and any advice will be highly appreciate.

```
class TaskGroupType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=58, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Project(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProjectOwners, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Owner'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    members = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProjectTeam, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="project"
    )
    tasktype = models.ManyToManyField(TaskType)

    class Meta:
        ordering =['created']
        verbose_name = "User Table"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=280, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        related_name='taskgroups', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering =['created']
        verbose_name = "Task Group"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Task(models.Model):
    SORT_TYPE = (
        (1, "Normal"),
        (2, "Urgent"),
        (3, "Very Urgent"),
    )
    createDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tasklist = models.ForeignKey(
        TaskList,
        related_name='tasks', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accomplished = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=380, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True)
    performer = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='Task', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    participant = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        related_name='+'
    )
    startDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    dueDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SORT_TYPE, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering =['createDate']
        verbose_name = "Task Table"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of your project

> 1. User can create Project
> 2. Project can have multiple Task
> 3. Each task belongs to a TaskGroup
> 4. Each project can have multiple members.

If the above use case is appropriate. Here is my model instances.

```
class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Task(models.Model):
    task_group = models.ForeignKey(TaskGroup)
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class ProjectTask(models.Model):
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
   task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
   ...

  # You can use Many field in Project model for Task reference if this model is not needed

class ProjectMember(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

    # You can use Many field in Project model instead if this model is not required
```

Having separate model for association adds in flexibility to control each association separately and extra parameters can be added.

*Example only contains association.*

Comment: Hi, thanks fo much for the answers, but I also need a `TaskGroupType` to save different `TaskGroup` templates, refer to the pics as link https://d.pr/free/i/j3VO3z  the first pic has default `TaskGoup`, and I can click `Type` to select different `TaskGroup` template, the third pic has three new fields more than the first pic.

Comment: You can extend the association accordingly. create a `TaskGroupType` model with foreign key to `TaskGroup`. Then you can get TaskGroupType for each TaskGroup.

Comment: Hi, I really wanted to accept your answer, but I am really sorry it still doesn't solve my question, when user add a template with 3-6 default fields, he also can add some custom fields, do you know how to make that default template with custom fields? https://d.pr/free/i/40eZQM https://d.pr/free/i/0RdJy4

Comment: are these the form fields? Do you want to dynamically add form fields?

Comment: I don't know whether they are the form fields, those fields can add and change somewhere, so I think they are form fields, yes, I want to dynamically add form fields, but I don't know how to add and save field and templates.